# 500 error while logout from backend in YII2

Tags: logout, yii2-advanced-app

I am getting 500 error while logout from backend in yii2 advanced template.
What are the causes of this error ? thank you in advance

Comment: Anything logged in `backend/runtime/logs/app.log`?

Comment: There should be error details that would give us some hints.

Comment: Hello @Bizley sorry i was busy in last 4-5 days so i could not replay you. Error logs are showing that  " mydomainname.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500"

Comment: Looks like a server problem. Run `requirements.php` file from the main folder in the console and see if there are any errors there.

Comment: yes, let me check

Comment: No errors in console

Comment: No warnings in `requirements.php`?

Comment: actually @Bizley it is woking fine on my localhost but error is coming when site is live. When user got log out it gives error 500 internal server error

Comment: yes warnings are there

Comment: ICU version Warning Internationalization support 
ICU Data version Warning Internationalization support

Comment: warnings are not in console

Comment: You need to check live server error log as well (log path depends on the server you are using, in case of Apache it's `/var/log/apache2` usually).

Comment: ok let me check @Bizley

Comment: There is nothing in server error logs. Is there anything else which can causes this error ? please suggest me answer @Bizley

Comment: I'm sorry but there is not enough information to give simple answer.